# Error: Highcharts error #13 ionic angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, highcharts, ionic-framework

i am new to HighCharts and want to use it to ionic. but i have a trouble and trying to determine what is wrong with my code. on console its showing some error message like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO1uy.png)

i have read question about it 
[Highcharts error #13 and AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970948/highcharts-error-13-and-angularjs)
[How can I fix Highcharts error #13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536233/how-can-i-fix-highcharts-error-13)
but still cannot found my problem
this is my controller

```
    .controller("homeController", function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.myDropDown = 'one';
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.submit = function () {
            var diagramlink = 'http://fendypradana.com/alfalahkeu/Apifalah/laporhari/format/json';

            var processed_json = [], kategori = [];
            $http.post(diagramlink, { tanggalawal: $scope.data.tglawal, tanggalakhir: $scope.data.tglakhir }).then(function (res) {

                console.log(res.data);
                console.log(res.data.data[2].tanggal);

                for (i = 0; i < res.data.data.length; i++) {
                    var dataint = parseInt(res.data.data[i].total)
                    processed_json.push(dataint);
                    kategori.push(res.data.data[i].tanggal);

                }
                console.log(processed_json)

                Highcharts.chart('containerhome', {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Diagram Pembayaran'
                    },

                    xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'coba1'
                        },
                        categories: kategori
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                                'Total Pembayaran: Rp.' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1);
                        }
                    },
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },

                    plotOptions: {

                    },

                    series: [
                        {
                            name: 'coba',
                            data: processed_json,

                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                rotation: -90,
                                color: '#FFFFFF',
                                align: 'right',
                                x: 4,
                                y: 10,
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '13px',
                                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    ]
                });
            })
        }
    })
```

**and this is my html**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="homeController">
            <select ng-model="myDropDown">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
            <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-show="myDropDown == 'two'">
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                     <span class="input-label">Pilih Bulan Awal</span>
                     <input type="date" ng-model="data.tglawal">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Pilih Bulan akhir</span>
                    <input type="date" ng-model="data.tglakhir">
    </label>
    <input class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit to server">
    <div class="card" style="width:95%; ng-controller=" homeController ">
            <div id="containerhome ">Placeholder for chart</div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Any suggestions would really help.

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: @Sajeetharan here http://plnkr.co/edit/rBB3moEVjMP94xgSWOPP?p=preview

Comment: i am seeing lot of references missing in your plunker. provide a team viewer i can check

Comment: how can i do that?@Sajeetharan

Comment: Install team viewer and share me the id https://www.teamviewer.com/en/

Comment: @Sajeetharan here my id 501 608 908

Comment: what is the password?

Comment: @Sajeetharan here 9467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your code, the problem is you are using highcharts-ng and using jquery way to bind the data,

Do this, inside the controller, define a config

```
 $scope.highchartsNG = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: assign your data
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Hello'
        },
        loading: false
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <highchart id="chart1" config="highchartsNG"></highchart>
```

Comment: I'm also  getting error like this 
angular.min.js?v=1:118 Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13